# Can I solve "returning address of local variable or temporary" without changing other functions in the code?

Tags: c, malloc, c2664

When running the following code I get the error:

```
returning address of local variable or temporary
```

trying to solve the issue my idea was to change `n_date` to:

```
char* n_date = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 60);
```

However, since I am not allowed to modify the function `output_fun`, with declaring `n_date` as a `char*` I get the error

```
Compile error c2664 'function' : cannot convert argument n from 'type1' to 'type2'
```

what could be a solution to this problem?

```
const char* funA(const char* input)
{
    struct tm date;
    char n_date[60];
    strftime(n_date, 80, "%B %d, %Y", &date);
    ouput_fun(n_date);
    return (const char*)&n_date;
}
```

Comment: `malloc` was the right direction (but the caller of `funA` then has the responsibility to call `free` on the pointer later on), but I don't understand the `c2664` error - there is no `type1`/`type2` in your code. Could you please show the exact code _and_ exact error (including line/column numbers) in case of the `malloc` attempt? Also, what is the exact function signature of `output_fun`? Also note there is a typo `ouput_fun` instead of `output_fun`, maybe this also messes something up?

Comment: One way would be to define as static: `static char n_date[60];` but the function will not be thread safe. Otherwise no amount of "consting" or casting will prevent the array from going out of life.

Comment: What was `const char* input` for? If you had `char* n_date` *there* instead, that is one way to get a string output. Anyway, where are you getting a value for `struct tm date`? The whole function seems confused.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide what type of argument ```output_fun``` expects.

Comment: The cast on the `return` is _not_ needed (the `const` is applied automatically). You can/should do: `return &n_date;` But, this only works for `char n_date[60];` With `char *n_date = malloc(60);`, then `&n_date` is a `char **` and _not_ `char *`. Do: `return n_date;` and it works for both cases. This solves the _returning pointer to stack variable_ issue [which was _not_ flagged]. **But**, the flagged issue is _not_ related to that. It is [has to be] that `output_fun` is (e.g.) `void output_fun(const int *)` and the error is converting `char *` to `int *` (or equivalent non-`char *` type)